# How to convert milliseconds to seconds with precision

Tags: java, precision, divide, milliseconds

I want to convert milliseconds to seconds (for example 1500ms to 1.5s, or 500ms to 0.5s) with as much precision as possible.

`Double.parseDouble(500 / 1000 + "." + 500 % 1000);` isn't the best way to do it: I'm looking for a way to get the remainder from a division operation so I could simply add the remainder on.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Surely you just need:

```
double seconds = milliseconds / 1000.0;
```

There's no need to manually do the two parts separately - you just need floating point arithmetic, which the use of `1000.0` (as a `double` literal) forces. (I'm assuming your `milliseconds` value is an integer of some form.)

Note that as usual with `double`, you may not be able to represent the result exactly. Consider using `BigDecimal` if you want to represent 100ms as 0.1 seconds *exactly*. (Given that it's a physical quantity, and the 100ms wouldn't be exact in the first place, a `double` is probably appropriate, but...)

Comment: If you use an `int / 1000.0` you will not see the representation error if you convert back to a String, it will be in the margin it corrects for.

Comment: Thanks, never knew it was that simple!

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you simply try

```
System.out.println(1500/1000.0);
System.out.println(500/1000.0);
```

Comment: Thanks, I would've picked this as the best answer but Jon's was slightly more detailed

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too, somehow my code did not present the exact values but rounded the number in seconds to 0.0 (if milliseconds was under 1 second).
What helped me out is adding the decimal to the division value.

```
double time_seconds = time_milliseconds / 1000.0;   // add the decimal
System.out.println(time_milliseconds);              // Now this should give you the right value.
```